# Points $P$ and $Q$ are on sides $\overline{CB}$ and $\overline{CD}$, respectively, of square $ABCD$ such that $CP=CQ=AB/4$. Find $\tan \angle PAQ$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Points $P$ and $Q$ are on sides $\overline{CB}$ and $\overline{CD}$, respectively, of square $ABCD$ such that $CP=CQ=AB/4$. Find $\tan \angle PAQ$.
[image]

I figured out that the two triangles are 3-4-5 triangles, and that the tanPAQ = tan(90-2PAB). I have tried to use a calculator, however I require an exact value. Here is the value outputted by the calculator:  0.291666

Comment: You can calculate $\cot(2 x)$ once you know $\cot(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$
\tan(90- 2x) = \cot 2x = \frac{\cos 2x}{\sin 2x} = \frac{\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x}{2\sin x \cos x}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much! the answer is 7/24.  I completely forgot about this!